# Persons & Addresses Table Relation in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table `Persons` with `Id` and `Name` columns.
Let's say `Id=100`, `Name = Al`

Address table:

- Id=1, Address= 123 Street, FK_Persons=100,
- Id=2, Address= Near Building#22, FK_Persons=100

Is this one to many relationship?

Comment: yes. It is. One person can have several addresses

Comment: Several people can live at the same address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a one to many relationship, if there are no other constraints on the tables.
You can create multiple addresses and assign it to one Person object, that's why it is a [one-to-many relationship](https://vertabelo.com/blog/one-to-many-relationship/).

Answer (score 0):

For a single, **unique** address, you can have **zero to one** person

Address -> Person : 0, 1

For a single, **unique** person, you can have **zero to many** addresses

Person -> Address : 0, N

You then end up with a relationship such as : (0, 1) : (0, N), which can be simplified to 1 : N

This is indeed a one to many relationship